# Next Js build failure due to window object in JS library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am importing lib.js file in a component as following -

```
import { xyz } from '@/public/lib.js'
```

This lib.js uses the window object which is causing the build to fail with the following error -

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I can not change the code in lib.js. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really comment this due to low reputation. However, the solution to this issue has been mentioned in the attached discussion thread.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42319#discussioncomment-4061453